# how to convert bash script for avro schema generator to java code

Tags: bash

I want to write java code for the  Avroschema which is in Bash format. I try to write the code but I am stuck at the create hive temp table for that also I have to generate .avsc file for that given avro hive table.

Comment: If you could show us some of the code you are working with, it would be easier to help.

Comment: I cannot imagine there is a bash-to-java conversion tool. You need to do it manually.